# Remove all users from site except one using WP CLI

Tags: users, wp-cli

I want to remove all users from the WordPress site using WP CLI except one (me, as administrator).

This command will remove all users:

```
wp user delete $(wp user list --field=ID --number=10)
```

Unfortunately (or not) no one has a role except the administrator. So I cannot filter based on this information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found out you can pass the `--exclude` option to `wp user list` to exclude a user by their ID from the list. So let's assume your user ID is `2` then you could do the following:

```
wp user delete $(wp user list --field=ID --exclude=2)
```

And just to be sure all content gets reassigned to you that would be the following command.

```
wp user delete $(wp user list --field=ID --exclude=2) --reassign=2
```

Comment: If I need to exclude more then one user I can use something like --exclude=2,3?

Comment: @natas – Yes, exactly. You can simply try it out yourself with `wp user list` against `wp user list --exclude=2,3,4,5`.

Comment: what to add in --field=id

Comment: WARNING: Don't use this if you intend to delete Users on a staging server. Perhaps I can save some troubles for others. I did not know it because I have a different coding background, but I `cd` to my staging folder and used `wp user delete` but it started to delete from my production server. It would have been correct to use `wp_staging`.

Comment: LOOOOOOOOOOOOOL